# Group by an element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group

So I have a dataframe on Python that has lots of variables happening at once and getting pulled off at the same time and I want to make them into a new dataframe thats grouped by time so for example its like:

| Value | ID | Unit | Key | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | m/s^2 | Acceleration | 01/01/2000 12:00:01 |
| On | 11 | String | Machine | 01/01/2000 12:00:01 |
| 2.0 | 12 | bar | Pressure | 01/01/2000 12:00:01 |
| 12 | 13 | m/s^2 | Acceleration | 01/01/2000 12:00:02 |
| Off | 14 | String | Machine | 01/01/2000 12:00:02 |
| 1.5 | 15 | bar | Pressure | 01/01/2000 12:00:02 |

but I want to have it as:

| Date | Acceleration | Pressure | Lid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2000 12:00:01 | 10 m/s^2 | 2.0 bar | On |
| 01/01/2000 12:00:02 | 12 m/s^2 | 1.5 bar | Off |

I can link the values togther but how do I go about grouping like that over multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to rework your columns, then `pivot`:

```
# merge value/unit except for "Machine"
df['value'] = np.where(df['Key'].eq('Machine'),
                       df['Value'],
                       df['Value'].astype(str)+' '+df['Unit'])

# replace "Machine" with "Lid"
df['col'] = df['Key'].replace({'Machine': 'Lid'})

# pivot using the new columns
df2 = (df
 .pivot(index='Date', columns='col', values='value')
 .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
                  Date Acceleration  Lid Pressure
0  01/01/2000 12:00:01     10 m/s^2   On  2.0 bar
1  01/01/2000 12:00:02     12 m/s^2  Off  1.5 bar
```